# Laravel 5.2 Validation Rules Order

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I did a custom Validation Rule that iterates over an array of objects that contains a key `dates` and check if those dates are consecutives (the difference between dates are just 1 day). For that, I need the 'day' key to be filled and have a correct date format. I put the `date_format` validator rule in the `day` key but as my custom Rule is in the array field It crash when I don't give him a correct date_format (for example a random string). Maybe you understan better with the code.

**Custom Validator Rule**

```
Validator::extend('consecutive_dates', function($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    // Order the in the array with the 'day' value
    usort($value, array($this, 'compare_dates'));
    $previous_date = null;
    foreach ($value as $date) {
    // Check if dates are consecutives
        $current_date = new DateTime($date['day']);
        if ($previous_date !== null) {
            $interval = $current_date->diff($previous_date);
            if ($interval->days !== 1) {
                // If not, fails
                return false;
            }
        }
        $previous_date = $current_date;
    }
    return true;
);
```

**Rules definition**

```
'dates.*.day' => 'required_with:dates|date_format:Y-m-d',
'dates' => 'bail|array|filled|consecutive_dates',
```

Now if I try to validate something like this:

```
"dates": [{
    "day": "fdsa",
}]
```

It will crash and say

```
DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (fdsa) at position 0 (f): The timezone could not be found in the database
```

The question is: Is there a way to tell Laravel to first Validate that the `'dates.*.day'` must have `date_format: Y-m-d` so It won't fail on the custom validation?

Answer (score 0):

You should check given value is valid date or not firstly, like this

```
if (Carbon::createFromFormat('date format', $date['day']) !== false) {
        // valid date
}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Do you mean in my custom validation? I know i can check it in the custom validation but I already have that validation with `date_format:Y-m-d` so I didn't want to repeat myself. That's why I was wondering if there was something like an order of rules in Laravel or I have to check it again.

Comment: yes, I mean check your custom validation, Can you check these params `$attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator` on custom controller, Maybe these are consist date format, so you don't repeat yourself.